# Update C# application replace .exe file

Tags: c#, web-services, download, webserver, exe

I have managed to get my application checking for updates with a `WebService` on my server and It will see if any update is there to be made. But the real problem I am facing right now is that I have no idea how to download the newer version of `.exe` of my application and replace the current one I'm running.

In conclusion I need to know how to download the newer version of `.exe` of my application and replace the current one I'm running.

Answer (score 4):

Well actually you need to create a separate process to handle the update steps. I have once developed a desktop application with the ability to receive updates form a web server and i did that by creating a different process that roles as the main entry point to the main application.

it starts the main application process while it keeps running to check for updates. Then if any updates available it download them to a temp folder after that it notifies the main application before closing it then it commits the new updates and restart the main application again.

But if you want to stick with one executable and one process. I guess you can't replace any executable while it is running that's not allowed by the OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a separate bootstrap application to do the work for you, as otherwise the app with be running so the OS will prevent you from overwriting it.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually there is way. I discovered it years ago.

You cannot delete the current executing .exe program file.  But you can move it.

So, I download the update file from my web server to an 
      /updates/myprogram.exe

Then I 
    1) File.Delete any previous myprogram.bak file
    2) File.Move the myprogram.exe to myprogram.bak.
    3) File.Copy the /updates/myprogram.exe to /myprogram.exe location.
    4) ask the user if they want to restart, calling Application.Restart()

Voila.  Problem resolved in your main program. No need to a boot program.

Comment: Maybe **post some code? Your explanation may be hard for people to understand.**

Comment: Also, attempting to move the **exe** while it is open will cause a **File is being used by another process** error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using additional process to replace the running exe file you can use CMD.
First, you have to run MyApp.exe. Your MyApp.exe has to check for updates, download and unpack files to %AppData%//Temp folder. Then your MyApp.exe starts CMD command (see below) that shuts down an old MyApp.exe, copies all files to the MyApp.exe folder and starts new version of MyApp.exe. So CMD acts as an installer.

```
var exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var exeFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);     
var command = "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul & echo \"Done!\" & taskkill /f /t /im "
                + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name 
                + ".exe & ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul & xcopy \""
                + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) 
                + "\\Temp\\\" \""+ exeFolderPath + "\" /h /i /c /k /e /r /y & call \"cmd /c start "
                + exeFolderPath + "\\"
                + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".exe\" & echo \"Enjoy the new version...\" & pause";


System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K " + command);
```