# Update c# application from that application-exe replace

Tags: c#-2.0

I am developing an application where I need the provide update of the application. Simply  replace the current exe file with the one from a web server.

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891580/update-c-sharp-application-replace-exe-file). But its not helpful. Please advice any concept.

Comment: In what way was the linked question not helpful?  What additional help do you need?  There are [numerous related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+c%23+update+application) beyond just that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://my-site.com/myfile.exe", @"c:\myfile.exe");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Windows Store](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/store/register). They provide everything necessary for doing this. Going this way might require more effort, but the result will be nice from a lot of perspectives.